# Understanding promse.reject() and how to pass object as parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am passing response.json in Promise.reject() so that it is available in catch. 
However in catch it comes as undefined.

```
const checkResponse = (response) => {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return response.json();
    }
    else{
    return Promise.reject(response.status,response.json());
  }
}
```

Following is the catch block

```
.catch((status,resp) => {
        console.log('Request failed', status, resp);
      });
```

resp in catch appears as "undefined"

Comment: First of all, `Promise.reject` takes only a single parameter.

Comment: which is an Error

Answer (score 2):

`reject` only accepts **one** argument. If you want to pass multiple pieces of data, then you need to bundle them up in (for example) an object.

```js
var p = new Promise(
  (res, rej) => rej({
    status: "status",
    data: {
      some: "object"
    }
  })
);
p.catch(reason => console.log("Rejected", reason.status, reason.data));
```

Answer (score 1):

`.reject` (and `.resolve`) only take one argument. You could pass this as an object:

```
return Promise.reject({ status: response.status, body: response.json() });
```

Also using `return response.json();` seems inconsistent. If it returns a promise, then you can't use it in the `Promise.reject` since you'll get the promise back rather than the body. If it doesn't return a promise, you're only returning a promise for the failure condition.

Comment: Yes, it does return a promise. Your constructed object isn't much more helpful than directly rejecting with the `response`.

Comment: True, you could just do `Promise.reject(response)`

Comment: Should only accept an Error object. Not like `Promise.resolve` that can accept anything.